# Change for a specific recordtype and field type

Tags: lightning-web-components

I need your assistance for the below code and add the message should only work for specific recordtype and a specific field value right now its written and message is showing for all recordtype and field values needed just for a specific how should I do that? Below is my Javascript code.

```
// recordPageMessage.js
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ANNUAL_ATTESTATION_RECORDTYPE_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Annual_Attestation__c.RecordTypeId';

export default class RecordPageMessage extends LightningElement {
     message = 'Effective Date should be January 1st of the Calendar Year listed on the form';
    isVisible = false;
    @api recordId;
    recordTypeName;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [ANNUAL_ATTESTATION_RECORDTYPE_NAME] })
    getAnnualAttestationRecord({ data, error }) {
    //console.log(data.recordTypeInfo.name);    
    if (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.recordTypeInfo.name);
        this.isVisible = true;
    }
    if (error) {
        console.log('err',error);
     } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.